# What may cause the KeyNotFoundException when trying to open a MySQL connection

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I trying to connect my database using C# code, but getting a KeyNotFoundException when the debugger gets to MySqlConnection Open method.

I Have tried changing my connectionString to another template, restarting my SQL server, and manually validating my server details (Username, Password ETC...)

```
//setting my connection data
private void Initialize() {
    server = "127.0.0.1";
    database = "database";
    uid = "root";
    password = "123456";
    String connectionString;
    connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
    database + ";" + "Uid=" + uid + ";" + "PWd=" + password + ";";
    connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
}


//Opening the connection
private bool OpenConnection() {
    try {
        connection.Open();//This is where I get my Exception
        return true;
    }
}
```

As I except connection I am getting the next Exception:

> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
>   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.CharSetMap.GetCharacterSet(DBVersion version, String CharSetName)
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.CharSetMap.GetEncoding(DBVersion version, String CharSetName)
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Configure(MySqlConnection connection)
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
>   at sqlTesting.DBConnect.OpenConnection() in d:\Users\moshe\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\sqlTesting\sqlTesting\DBConnect.cs:line 40

Comment: [This might help...](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/)

Comment: @RahulSharma Where is collation-server? in the SQL workbench or in Visual studio?

Comment: @MosheYakobovich In SQL Workbench.

Comment: This works for me "Server=xxx;Database=xxx; Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx;CharSet=utf8;"; - I think you are missing the ';' after each varrible

Answer (score 4):

You should try removing `collation-server` settings in your `Options` tab under `General` settings and restart your `MySQL` server to resolve this issue.

OR

You can simply add the `charset` to the connection string:

```
Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Database=database;User ID=root;Password=123456;CharSet=utf8;
```

OR

If your framework is `.NET`, then all you need to do is to make sure that your 'MySql.Data.dll' is up to date with the corresponding version.