# C# MySQL MySqlConnection connectionstring for empty password

Tags: c#, mysql, database, database-connection

I am trying to connect C# and database MySQL : using `MySql.Data.MySqlClient;`
My codes are as below. I am getting error. I think it is because of empty password.

```cs
string connstring = @"server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=client";

MySqlConnection dbcon =  new MySqlConnection(connstring);
```

Comment: Would you like us to guess the error?

Comment: I got the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449718/what-may-cause-the-keynotfoundexception-when-trying-to-open-a-mysql-connection  THANK U

Comment: I am glad i could help - *looks around nervously*

Answer (score -1):

if you don't want to expose the password in connect string. you can use the Windows authentication instead.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/authentication-in-sql-server